# Spark Yarn integration on Hortonworks Sandbox 2.4

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hortonworks-data-platform

I'm running the Hortonworks sandbox 2.4 which comes with Spark 1.6.0. Trying to run a sample spark program and I'm able to submit it successfully with spark-submit. As I need to use this spark jar file in an external application, trying to use the "java -jar" command to achieve the same output as in spark-submit.

I'm using maven to build and used the maven shade plugin to build a fat jar as I was facing issues with the class not found exception earlier for the dependencies "spark-core_2.10" & "spark-yarn_2.10" artifacts. Now those issues are resolved.

However, the jar file is referring to the yarn-default.xml that comes with the dependencies inside the fat jar and not using the yarn-site.xml present in the Hortonworks sandbox. This is causing issues as below as it is not able to copy the file into hdfs.

java.io.FileNotFoundException: File file:/tmp/spark-1b318406-c7a1-4a94-9605-d6a46f0170d4/__spark_conf__5199620712586647591.zip does not exist

How can I make this jar file point to the Hortonworks sandbox settings from this default ones? If I don't build the fat jar, it was throwing the exception as below.

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/api/java/function/Function

Comment: You have two different errors there 1) are you trying to point to HDFS? If so, yarn-site.xml doesn't control that 2) you'd be getting a ClassNotFoundException if you missed some dependencies in Maven for Spark

Comment: Also, Spark has a standalone server mode that you can download and use in its own. There's no reason to limit yourself to running it in a VM

Comment: Hi @cricket_007 ..I need to prepare this spark jar file so it can be called from a Spring application (Spring Cloud Dataflow). Right now, I'm able to resolve the class not found error by adding the dependencies to pom.xml. My next step is to make this a runnable jar so it can be copied to the spring application as an executable. As the Spring application is also hosted on Yarn, trying to make it work in yarn-client mode.

Comment: This jar should be in a position to pick the yarn properties from the sandbox and not the default ones that are downloaded as part of the maven dependencies...

Comment: I see. Well, if Spark is reading from HDFS, it'll need a configured hdfs-site, most likely. I've never ran Spark on YARN, though, so I'm not sure what you'll need there. And I'm not sure what YARN properties Maven would manage